# Fine-tuning HTML5 Phonegap app

Tags: performance, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

Have managed to build an HTML5 application. following libraries have used for that:

- jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js
- jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min
- lawnchair.js

Every thing works fine Wrapped it with Phonegap **cordova-2.0.0**

But have noticed the application is very slow.

My application actually does **ajax** request gets **Json** and loads the UI (Mostly **listviews**)

Are there any performance improving techniques to make my application work faster?

Also any Tools to test the same?

Targeting Platforms : **Android** and **iOS** .

**EDIT**:

one thing have noticed is cache size of the application is increasing on every `click` and `page` transition (times it reaches in MB's).. though have disabled ajax cache.. do i need to take care of someother things?

Comment: For which mobile platform have you created the Cordova build? Because the performance also depends on browser rendering speed. Safari is slightly faster in rendering compared to most of the Android browsers.

Comment: @AzizShaikh :Mostly targeting Android>2.2 and iOS ..Is there any thing do with cache? as i can see the cache increases after each ajax call?

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh: "slightly" is an understatement. Before Chrome for Android we could be talking a 1/10 performance ratios regarding Html5 Canvas.

Comment: Wrote a couple of tips to make the most of what you got in a webview app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904315/android-webview-late-rendering/14010732#14010732 . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You Can increase speed of app by:
**1.** Using minified versions of js which you have included in you project.
**2.** Avoid using images with bigger size. tune them with web compatible PNG files
Optimize Images
Use CSS Sprite Sheets
[image]

```
   .icon {
      width: 14px; height: 14px;
      background-image: url("glyphicons-halflings.png");
    }
    .icon-glass {
      background-position: 0 0;
    }
    .icon-music {
      background-position: -24px 0;
    }
    .icon-search {
      background-position: -48px 0;
    }
```

Use the right image size (don't scale images in HTML)
Host images on scalable, distributed systems (i.e. S3)
Avoid 404s for images

```
<img src="{{pic}}" onerror='this.src="nopic.jpg"'/>
```

**3.** Avoid using much of CSS.Limit Shadows and Gradients link box-shadow,border-radius,gradients,text-align
Try disabling some of the CSS that slows it down(Simon MacDonald's idea). In your jquery mobile .css file add this to the bottom:

```
* {
text-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0 !important;
}
```

**4.** Use CSS Transitions + Hardware Acceleration Use Native Scrolling

**5.** If you are using any Live url to get JS better download them and use locally.
**6.** [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) FastClick is a simple, easy-to-use library for eliminating the 300ms delay between a physical tap and the firing of a click event on mobile browsers.(jjsquared's idea)

**7.** use Slpash screen.

**8.** Avoid using framework use only if necessary. Try to make responsive design.

**9.** Don't generate the UI on the server.Create the UI in JavaScript at the client-side

**10.** Minimize Reflows

- Reduce the number of DOM elements.
- Minimize access to the DOM Update    elements "offline" before
  reinserting into DOM.
- Avoid tweaking    layout in JavaScript

**slow**

```
$("#header a.back").on("click", clickHandler);
$("#header a.back").css("color", "white");
$("#header a.back").css("text-decoration", "none");
$("#header a.back").attr("href", "#");
```

**Fast**

```
var $backButton = $("#header a.back");
$backButton.on("click", clickHandler);
$backButton.css("color", "white");
$backButton.css("text-decoration", "none");
$backButton.attr("href", "#");
```

**11.** Avoid Network Access
Dont make network dependend apps for getting content

```
$.ajax({url: "services/states"}).done(function(data) {
    states = data;
});
```

use Cache Static Data LocalStorage, Database & File
**slow**

```
$.ajax({url: "slow/feed"}).done(function(data) {

});
```

**fast**

```
dataAdapter.getItems().done(function(data) {

});
```

**12.** Don't wait for the data to display the UI

```
// Display view
displayView();

// Get data
$.ajax({url: "product/101"}).done(function(product) {
    // Update view
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make it more performant on Android you should disable some of the CSS:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081339/41679

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip.. It has really improved performance, but one thing have noticed is `cache` size of the application is increasing on every click and page transition (times it reaches in MB's).. though have disabled ajax cache.. do i need to take care of someother things?

Comment: Sorry, I try to avoid JQM whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you could you please list down alternatives other than JQM ..My app is very simple not much animation ..just for business purposes dealing with Online data.

Comment: Well you could roll your own CSS or use Dojo Mobile. Sencha, Kendo UI, XUI, jqTouch, Zepto.js, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info, But I dont think it will be possible for  us to change the application with another framework at this point. WIll definitely take your suggestion for my othe rprojects.. but any Hint about why the cache grows that much, That will atleast sort me out for the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mechanism called pre-fetch, it loads the page before you click it. So that redirection is faster. But you are using more transfer.

It is used like this:

```
<a href="prefetchThisPage.html" data-prefetch> ... </a>
```

Check this site:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip ...Am basicallly loading the  listview dynamically and even the pages an dthe content are loaded using mobile.changePage ..does `data-prefetch` helps in my case?

Answer (score 0):

To increase click performance and to avoid the 300ms browser delay that's natively built into mobile browsers, you should use a library such as FastClick.  This will drastically reduce the lag in between mobile.changePage calls.

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick